# How to connect Firebase Realtime Database to my C# project?

Tags: c#, firebase, winforms, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect to a Realtime Database in C# Windows Forms. I want to create a chat app using it, and to observe the child with a current chat ID.
Meaning, that I want to observe any changes (to see new messages), and display them to the user. Is there any way to do that with Firebase?

Comment: [Understanding the Firebase Observe Function](https://medium.com/@oleary.audio/understanding-the-firebase-observe-function-14c9f73808bc)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Seems like it is a solution for iOS.  Is there any solution for C#?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/).  Near the bottom of the page, where it says "Listen Streaming from the REST API."